# linux: kill all my processes but not this terminal

Tags: linux, bash, kill

I want an easy way in linux to kill all my current processes.

The problem with `kill -9 -1` is that it also kills the current terminal. Is there an easy way to kill everything except the current terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kills all processes except the ones associated with the current terminal:

```
kill `ps -o pid= -N T`
```

Comment: doesn't work under debian. ps lists all processes

Comment: The "T" argument to "ps" selects all processes associated with the current terminal and "-N" will negate that.

Comment: That may well be ... but if executed as root or under sudo that brings down the system.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048310/linux-vm-rhel-7-down-on-issuing-kill-ps-o-pid-n-t-and-doesnt-come-up :D

Answer (score 2):

But just want to say don't use -9 as a knee jerk mechanism as it should be used as a last resort. It can't be caught by the process and doesn't let a process cleanup its resources.

Try maybe kill -15 instead to start.